# How do I use Selenium to click on a button that can't be inspected?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

When I hover over a button there is text that says something. The button itself has no text on it or around it.

However, I can't inspect the element using F12.

How can I use Selenium to click this button?

Would it be something like the below code?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button/title[contains(.,'**Text**')])[2]").click();
```

When I use this code however it says

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//button/title[contains(.,'**Text**')])[2]"}"
```

Comment: Have you tried using `selector`? Or other  variations for the `find_element_by` maybe it can pull the info you need.

Comment: You can use the Selenium IDE plugin for your browser.

Comment: "However, I can't inspect the element using F12." are you sure about that? It looks like some JavaScript is involved. Please post a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JavascriptExecutor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript(Script,Arguments);
```